# Python でファイルに書き込んだ float のリストを読み込んで利用したい

Tags: python, python3

Pythonでファイルに書き込んだfloatのリストが読み込めません。
リストから読み込むときに文字列として[[や0　.　などとなってしまい本来の小数に戻せません。
書き込みと読み込み双方どなたか教えていただけないでしょうか？

Comment: jsonにするのが簡単で汎用性があるのでは？ [第13章.Pythonオブジェクトをシリアライズする](http://diveintopython3-ja.rdy.jp/serializing.html), [【Python】jsonで自作クラスを含んだデータをシリアライズ/デシリアライズする](http://segafreder.hatenablog.com/entry/2017/10/01/140125)

Comment: 恥ずかしながらJsonというものを知りませんでした。これが簡単であれば使ってみようと思います。

Comment: 作成したファイルを手作業で編集することを考えないのであれば、pickleはどうでしょうか。下記はPython3.8のドキュメントですが、３.7とかでも使えると思います。[pickle --- Python オブジェクトの直列化 — Python 3.8.5 ドキュメント](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/pickle.html)

Comment: 情報ありがとうございます。検討させていただきます。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> リストから読み込むときに文字列として[[や0　.　などとなってしまい本来の小数に戻せません。

とのことですが、もしかしてこれは多次元の NumPy array をファイルに保存しようとなさってませんでしょうか。`[[` が出力されているのは 1 次元ではなくて多次元のリストを出力した際の挙動です。また `0.0` を `0.` と省略して出力するのは Python の普通の配列ではデフォルトだと行われないはずで、NumPy array などではデフォルトで行われます。

であれば、NumPy にはファイル書きこみおよび読み込み用の関数が用意されています。ドキュメントにコードサンプルが載っていますのでドキュメントにリンクしています。

- バイナリ形式：[`np.save`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.save.html)、[`np.load`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.load.html)
- テキスト形式：[`np.savetext`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html)、[`np.loadtext`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html)

Answer (score 2):

ファイルはテキスト／バイナリのどちらで作成しようとしていますか？

以下に簡単なファイル入出力の例を挙げておきます。
各APIの詳細はPythonのリファレンスを参照してください。

- [7. 入力と出力 — Python 3.8.5 ドキュメント](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html)

テキストはエンドユーザーが直接読み書きすることもできますが、読み込み時のバリデーションの実装が難しくなります。また、浮動小数点数の場合、10進数で出力すると誤差が生じるケースがあります。指数形式で有効桁数をできる限り大きくするほうがよいですが、ファイルサイズが大きくなりがちです。拡張性や自己記述性の観点から、XML形式などの階層化に対応したフォーマットを採用することもあります。

バイナリはファイルサイズを削減でき、読み込み時のバリデーションの実装が比較的容易というメリットがありますが、エンドユーザーが読み書きするのには適していません。システム間の相互運用の観点から、数値の内部表現にも配慮する必要がありますが、Pythonの`struct`モジュールでは、プラットフォームの実装によらずIEE 754準拠の浮動小数点数バイナリ表現が使用されるので、移植性や可搬性は確保されています。

- [struct --- バイト列をパックされたバイナリデータとして解釈する — Python 3.8.5 ドキュメント](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/struct.html)

```
import os
import struct

def printFilePathAndSize(path):
    print('Path = "%s", Size = %d [bytes]' % (path, os.path.getsize(path)))

path1 = 'test.txt'
path2 = 'test.bin'

srcList = [-10.5, -0.01, 0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4]

# (1) Text format.

with open(path1, encoding='utf-8', mode='w') as f:
    for x in srcList:
        f.write(format(x, '.15e') + '\n')

printFilePathAndSize(path1)

dstList = []
with open(path1, encoding='utf-8', mode='r') as f:
    while True:
        line = f.readline()
        if not line:
            break;
        dstList.append(float(line))
        # For test.
        print(line.replace('\r', '').replace('\n', ''))

print(dstList)

# (2) Binary format.

structOfDoubleFloat = struct.Struct('d')

with open(path2, mode='wb') as f:
    for x in srcList:
        f.write(structOfDoubleFloat.pack(x))

printFilePathAndSize(path2)

dstList = []
with open(path2, mode='rb') as f:
    while True:
        binData = f.read(8)
        if not binData:
            break;
        # Get the first element of tuple.
        dstList.append((structOfDoubleFloat.unpack(binData))[0])

print(dstList)
```